# Django File Upload: How do I handle the file?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-file-upload

I have read the documentation several times, but I am still confused. When you specify a model in Django, you can specify the file's destination. However, in the documentation, they go on a great deal about handling the write to disk manually. My question is: Is it better to just say `form.save()` or to write a file handler with a hardcoded(?) path. `form.save()` has been flakey for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling the form's save method should work just fine, assuming you are using a `forms.ModelForm` subclass. Some things to note.

- Make sure to properly set the form's **enctype** in the template
- Be sure the view that handles the form checks for files

  `form=MyModelForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)`

When you say `form.save()` has been flaky, what do you mean?

Comment: I am saving a modelform but for some reason it's not showing up :(

Comment: I think it was mostly my fault. I'm trying to get it to work when the submitted form has errors.